# how to find a Lmax Disruptor diamond(one producer 5 consumer 1 conclude)example?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

i find the user guide of Lmax disrupter in github is very simple, now i have a problem with one producer and five cosumer, after that i need to conclude the result of the consumer, is there any demo, how to find a Lmax Disruptor diamond(one producer 5 consumer 1 conclude)example?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can provide several consumers via varags to `Disruptor.handleEventsWith`. Afterwards register the conclusion with a call of `then` (fluent DSL). The second call ensures that events are handled by all consumers before being passed to the concluding step.

A working example can look like this:

```
import com.lmax.disruptor.*;
import com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Diamond {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Disruptor<LongEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<>(LongEvent::new, 1024, executor, ProducerType.SINGLE, new SleepingWaitStrategy());

        //register five consumers and a final conclude
        disruptor.handleEventsWith(new Consumer(1), new Consumer(2), new Consumer(3), new Consumer(4), new Consumer(5)).then(new Conclude());

        disruptor.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            disruptor.publishEvent((event, sequence, newValue) -> event.setValue(newValue), i);
        }

        disruptor.shutdown();
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public static class Consumer implements EventHandler<LongEvent> {
        private int i;
        public Consumer(int i) { this.i = i; }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(LongEvent event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Consumer: " + i);
            event.setValue(event.getValue() + 1);
        }
    }

    public static class Conclude implements EventHandler<LongEvent> {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(LongEvent event, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Conclude: " + event.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static class LongEvent
    {
        private long value;

        public void setValue(long value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public long getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

The events simply contain a long value. The consumers increment the value, the final step prints it. The `for` loop puts three events with initial values 1, 2, and 3 into the ring.

Note that you do not need to synchronize the work on the `LongEvent` in the `Consumer` as the ringbuffer ensures that only one handler is working on an event at once. Furthermore note how the prints of the consumers vary on several runs.